# is it necessary to have multi valued attributes in an entity to be present when there is a relationship for that

Tags: database-design, foreign-keys, entity-relationship, multivalue

is it necessary to have multi valued attributes in an entity to be present when there is a relationship for that multi valued attribute whith 1:m cardinality.
for a example there is a table called tester and there is a multivalued att called raisedBugs and also there is a relationship with that tester entity called bugs which having tester_id as a foreign key(issue_assigner)

[image: ER figure]

Answer (score 0):

The multiplicity of your associations depends on the functional requirements for the application. 1:m means that each bug has exactly one tester who raised it, so the `tester_id` must be non-null and filled with a valid id of a tester for each record. If your requirements are less strict, e.g. because you have bugs found by other people who are not on your database, the multiplicity would be 0,1:m, and the foreign key may be null.

Comment: that's not the point i'm asking about.see the above updated question with the figure and tell that this multi valued raised_issues attribute is needed to be present in the iagram